# Should I make a global constant variable for forever-constant value such as a count of soccer players?

Tags: c++, coding-style, refactoring, constants

I'm writing a soccer simulator and I need to write number `11` multiple time in many source files.

I'm encountering two possible ways of writing my code in continue:

1. Writing `11` easily since it will never ever changes and don't mind my self; Or,
2. Making `const int COUNT_OF_SOCCER_PLAYERS=11`.

   If so, I should extract this constant in some header file (maybe `constants.h`) and `include` this header any source file that I need `11` !

What should I do now ?

**In other word, Why should I not write `11`. What's wrong with that?**

(Please answer the question in general for all forever-constant values)

Comment: You could do that (making it global in standard namespace). Just a question of personal preferences. But if: don´t use names which could be needed for other things.

Comment: Why not 11: So that other programmers reading the code (or you, somewhere in the future, after you forgot what you were thinking for each line) understand what is meant by 11 quickly, without thinking much.

Comment: Generally speaking, using "magic numbers" is bad because it's often hard to know what they mean. But it's not as clear-cut as that, since for specific program the number might be obvious. Having the number 52 in a card game, for example, or 11 in a football game, then it's pretty obvious what they mean, and they won't ever change. But for other numbers that might not be obvious, or might change depending on requirements, then using symbolic names is better.

Comment: You don't need to make such a long variable name, NPLAYERS would do the trick.  Usual reason is maintenance, in case it would change later.  THis is an improbable risk here.  But nevertheless, later, when you encounter NPLAYERS you know what it was about, whereas for 11 you can't be sure: it could be a special parameter for game mode, the max length of the player's name, the number of high scores you want to keep, etc...

Comment: Thanks All. I got the point :)

Comment: depending on how/where you use `11`, a constant `MAX_SOCCER_PLAYERS` might make your code more readable.

Comment: Another useful trick is to be able later to search/find in your code every line that use the number of player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should probably use a constant value, even if it may seem redundant, to increase the readability/flexibility of your code. I personally, would recommend putting it in the header file to keep the value in a single place

Answer (score 0):

If this COUNT_OF_SOCCER_PLAYERS is used by many modules then it would best to make a seperate header file where you would put all const.

Through this way usage of const is localized to one place and surely it helps in maintainence.